# Submitting contents of file to a Django view in HTML

Tags: python, html, django

I'm working with Django v1.4 (Python v.2.7.3) and I'm trying to build a proofchecking application. My proofchecker has an "Examples" page with a list of links to example proofs for the user, and these are rendered on the screen one after the other. A small sample is shown below:

[image]

These example files are saved at MEDIA_ROOT on the server, and what I want is a way to make it so that clicking the link will pass the contents of the file in a POST message to a particular view. That view already has code designed to handle the user uploading a proof file directly from their file system, so essentially what I want to do is make it so that the examples.html template (shown below) passes the same kind of information except for files already stored on the server.

The code for examples.html is:

```
{% load staticfiles %}

<html>
<head>
  <title>Anaconda</title>
  <style>
  body
  {
    overflow-y: scroll;
  }
</style>

</head>

<body>

<center>
<a href="/server"><img src="{% static "AnacondaTitleText.png" %}" alt="Title" height="40%" width="40%"/></a>

<div align="left" style="width:800px;">
<h2>Anaconda Examples</h2>
<p>You can click the button beside each example on this page to load it into the proof window.

{% if examples %}
The following examples are included with Anaconda:</p>
<br>

{% for example in examples %}
    <p>{{ example.exampleFile.name|cut:"./" }}: <a href="{{ example.exampleFile.url }}">link</a></p>
    <br>
{% endfor %}

{% else %}
There are no examples currently included with Anaconda.</p>
{% endif %}

</div>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

The "a href..." part will need to be changed because currently, clicking it will bring up a "Save file" dialog which is not what I want.

In my server's views.py file, I have the following code capable of handling uploaded files:

```
def proof(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        defaultText = request.FILES['docfile'].read()
        proofText = ProofForm(request.POST)
    else:
        defaultText = ""
        proofText = ProofForm()
    c = {}
    c.update(csrf(request))
    c['form'] = proofText
    c['default_text'] = defaultText
    return render_to_response('server/proof.html', c)
```

I suppose what I want is a way to do the following:

- The user clicks the link next to a particular example proof
- All the necessary information gets loaded into request.FILES
- This gets sent to the server as a POST request to proof(request)
- proof(request) treats it like a regular uploaded file and reads the file contents

My models.py file looks like this:

```
from django.db import models

class Example(models.Model):
    exampleFile = models.FileField(upload_to='.')
```

I'd be happy to provide additional information if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this, but I suspect it's a bit hacky.

Inside examples.html I include the following:

```
{% for example in examples %}
    <form name="example" action="/server/proof" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <p>{{ example.exampleFile.name|cut:"./" }}</p>
    <input type="hidden" name="example" value="{{ example.exampleFile.name|cut:"./" }}">
    <input type="submit" value="Select">
    </form>
    <br>
{% endfor %}
```

I associate the name of the file with a hidden input element, and then in views.py I have the following code:

```
def proof(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print "DATA"
        print str(request.POST)
        try:
          defaultText = request.FILES['docfile'].read()
        except:
          examplePath = request.POST.get('example')
          with open(join(MEDIA_DIR, examplePath), 'r') as f:
            defaultText = f.read()

        proofText = ProofForm(request.POST)
    else:
        defaultText = ""
        proofText = ProofForm()
    c = {}
    c.update(csrf(request))
    c['form'] = proofText
    c['default_text'] = defaultText
    return render_to_response('server/proof.html', c)
```

It's patchwork, but it does what I want. Hopefully I'll have time to improve the code at some later time.